# Нужна помощь в написании теста для консольных крестиков-ноликов

Tags: java, ооп, юнит-тесты, junit

У меня консольная программа крестики-нолики. Для тестирования ввода с консоли я использую класс `StubInput`:

```
public class StubInput implements In {

    /**
     * Contain answers required string type.
     */
    private String[] answersStr;

    /**
     * Counter for get next value from answersStr.
     */
    private int countStr = 0;

    /**
     * Contain answers required int type.
     */
    private int[] answersNum;

    /**
     * Counter for get next value from answersNum.
     */
    private int countNum = 0;

    public void setAnswersStr(String[] answersStr) {
        this.answersStr = answersStr;
    }

    public void setAnswersNum(int[] answersNum) {
        this.answersNum = answersNum;
    }

    /**
     * Emulator string input stream.
     * @return string answer.
     */
    @Override
    public String getStrInput() {
        return this.answersStr[this.countStr++];
    }

    /**
     * Emulator int input stream.
     * @return int answer.
     */
    @Override
    public int getNumInput() {
        return this.answersNum[this.countNum++];
    }
}
```

И для класса отвечающего за доску в котором есть возможность выбора размера доски это сработало:

```
public class Desc implements Board {

    /**
     * Information about statement desc for bot.
     */
    private static char[][] infoDesc;


    /**
     * Input for get console in.
     */
    private In input = new Input();

    /**
     * Desc for game.
     */
    private char[][] desc = new char[3][3];

    /**
     * Pointer on desc. It's information for bot about statement desc.
     *
     * @return current statement desc.
     */
    public static char[][] getInfoDesc() {
        return infoDesc;
    }

    /**
     * Use for test class StubInput.
     *
     * @param input emulation console input stream.
     */
    @Override
    public void setInput(In input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for desc. Init infoDesc.
     *
     * @return desc.
     */
    @Override
    public char[][] getDesc() {
        infoDesc = this.desc;
        return this.desc;
    }

    /**
     * For choice desc size.
     */
    @Override
    public void initDescSize() {
        System.out.println("Хотите использовать стандартный размер поля: y/n");
        String answer = this.input.getStrInput();
        if (answer.equals("y")) {
            System.out.println("Установлен стандартный размер поля: 3/3");
        } else if (answer.equals("n")) {
            this.initNonstandardDesc();
        }
        this.initContentDesc();
    }

    /**
     * Install desc nonstandard size.
     */
    private void initNonstandardDesc() {
        System.out.println("Введите размер сторон:");
        int i = this.input.getNumInput();
        this.desc = new char[i][i];
        System.out.println(format("Установлен размер поля: %s/%s", i, i));
    }

    /**
     * Fill desc empty call. Empty is ' '.
     */
    private void initContentDesc() {
        for (int i = 0; i != this.desc.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j != this.desc.length; j++) {
                this.desc[j][i] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот тест к нему:

```
public class DescTest {

    /**
     * Test choice standard desc size.
     * @see Desc#initDescSize()
     */
    @Test
    public void whenUserChoiceStandardDescSizeThenDeskSizeEqualTreeToTree() {
        StubInput input = new StubInput();
        Board desc = new Desc();
        input.setAnswersStr(new String[]{"y"});
        desc.setInput(input);

        desc.initDescSize();

        int result = desc.getDesc().length;
        assertThat(result, is(3));
    }

    /**
     * Test case when user choice nonstandard desc size.
     */
    @Test
    public void whenUserChoiceNonstandardThenSizeThenDeskSizeEqualUserInput() {
        StubInput input = new StubInput();
        Board desc = new Desc();
        input.setAnswersStr(new String[]{"n"});
        input.setAnswersNum(new int[]{5});
        desc.setInput(input);

        desc.initDescSize();

        int result = desc.getDesc().length;
        assertThat(result, is(5));
    }
}
```

Однако когда я попробовал протестировать класс самой игры у меня ничего не вышло. Вот сама игра:

```
public class Game implements Round {

    /**
     * Desc for play.
     */
    private Board desc = new Desc();

    /**
     * winner.
     */
    private Gamers winner;

    /**
     * For input.
     */
    private In input = new Input();

    /**
     * List contain all gamer: bot and user.
     */
    private ArrayList<Gamers> gamers = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Util class contain algorithm determining winner.
     */
    private Validation valid = new ValidationWinnerUtil();

    @Override
    public Gamers getWinner() {
        return this.winner;
    }

    /**
     * Check correct move.
     * @param player player which move.
     * @return true if move success. False if move fail
     */
    private boolean move(Gamers player) {
        player.setPosit();
        if (this.desc.getDesc()[player.getPosit().getY()][player.getPosit().getX()] == ' ') {
            this.desc.getDesc()[player.getPosit().getY()][player.getPosit().getX()] = player.getColor();
            return true;
        } else {
            System.err.println("Так ходить нельзя!");
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Determines fist move.
     */
    @Override
    public void firstMove() {
        this.desc.initDescSize();
        System.out.println("Кто ходит первым? Enter: Bot / I");
        if (this.input.getStrInput().toUpperCase().equals("BOT")) {
            this.fstMoveBot();
        } else {
            this.fstMoveUsr();
        }
        Printer.printDesc(this.desc.getDesc());
        this.loopMoves();
    }

    /**
     * Configurable statement game if bot move first.
     */
    private void fstMoveBot() {
        this.gamers.add(new Bot(Colors.X.getColor()));
        this.gamers.add(new User(Colors.O.getColor()));
    }

    /**
     * Configurable statement game if user choice move first.
     */
    private void fstMoveUsr() {
        this.gamers.add(new User(Colors.X.getColor()));
        this.gamers.add(new Bot(Colors.O.getColor()));
    }

    /**
     * Loop game process.
     */
    private void loopMoves() {
        Gamers winner = null;
        while (this.valid.gameCanGoOn(this.desc.getDesc())) {
            for (Gamers gamer : this.gamers) {

                if (this.valid.gameCanGoOn(this.desc.getDesc()) &&
                        this.move(gamer)
                        ) {

                    Printer.printDesc(this.desc.getDesc());
                    winner = gamer;

                } else if (this.valid.gameCanGoOn(this.desc.getDesc())) {
                    this.mistakeMove(gamer);
                    Printer.printDesc(this.desc.getDesc());
                }
            }
        }

        this.initResultGame(winner);
    }

    /**
     * Give more chance when player which mistake - try move in busy cell.
     * @param gamer player which mistake.
     */
    private void mistakeMove(Gamers gamer) {
        while (!this.move(gamer)) {
            mistakeMove(gamer);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Init result game.
     * @see TickTack#winners
     * @param winner gamer for estimated award.
     */
    private void initResultGame(Gamers winner) {
        if (!this.valid.emptyCellExist(  this.desc.getDesc()) &&
                !this.valid.winnerDetermines(this.desc.getDesc())
                ) {

            System.out.println("Ничья.");
        } else if (this.valid.winnerDetermines(  this.desc.getDesc())) {
            this.winner = winner;
            System.out.println(format("Победитель: %s", winner.getColor()));
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема заключается в том что когда метод `firstMove()` начинает работу то поток выполнения передается до самого конца партии, и у меня нет возможности для того чтобы подменить `Input` на `StubInput` в объекте пользователя вот тут:

```
private void fstMoveBot() {
        this.gamers.add(new Bot(Colors.X.getColor()));
        this.gamers.add(new User(Colors.O.getColor())); // вот тут new User
    }
```

Но и перед запуском `firstMove()` я тоже этой подмены сделать не могу так как `firstMove()` все равно их перепишет.

В общем такая проблема... С заранее не записать так как все равно перепишется, а в процессе вклинится не как. И даже если я и создам указатель на:

```
this.gamers.add(какой-то_указатель_с_полей = new User(Colors.O.getColor()))
```

это так же ничего не даст.

Помогите пожалуйста. Что мне делать? Как мне протестировать это? Может сам код г-но, потому и не тестируется тогда подскажите в чем. В общем вот. Буду безумно благодарен за помощь и любую конструктивную критику...

Comment: Вы писали тесты после кода? Так?

Comment: Да каюсь... После кода(((

Comment: давайте уточним, что вы хотите - TDD или просто написать тесты к этому коду?

Comment: Написать тесты к этому коду. Но как это сделать не пойму((( Очень хочется сделать это так что-бы все не переделывать. Помогите.

Comment: выберите метод - к которому написать тест?

Comment: firstMove() это единственный публичный метод в Game  но он тянет за собой все и в этом проблема которая поставила меня в тупик. Но если мне удасться протестировать его не меняя код то все остальное я тоже смогу сделать. Но он тянет за собой loopMoves() а значит надо всю партию тестировать я же не могу его остановить

Comment: То что вы хотите написать - это интеграционный тест. Я бы рекомендовал начинать с юнит тестов. Возьмите один класс с понятным вам интерфейсом и напишите к нему тест. Например, класс Desc (должен называться Desk), что он делает? Какие у него ответственности?

Comment: Устанавливает размер доски и инициализирует пробелами-чарами ' ' я эти тесты сделал он  там в вопросе есть. Там без проблем все прошло. А вот с Game классом затык. А через юнит тест я никак Game не протестировать? Я просто с интеграционными тестами совсем не знаком

Comment: у вас дизайн вашей системы не правильный. так что писать тесты будет очень сложно. да расширять систему тоже. у класса Desk зависимость от Input - это не правильно. вам надо переделать вопрос. на этот вариант ответить почти не возможно.

Comment: Desk не должна иметь поле input? может передать его из Game как параметр? Или вообще размер доски тут не трогать? Как думаете input вообще не должен фигурировать в классе Desk даже как локальная переменная или только как поле?

Comment: создайте новый вопрос. про дизайн класса Desk. а этот удалите.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610375/java-%D0%9E%D0%9E%D0%94-%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8 вот новый вопрос