# Нужна помощь в корректировке дизайна приложения крестики нолики

Tags: java, ооп, инспекция-кода, оод

Я сделал игру крестики нолики но как выяснилось когда я начал писать тесты что протестировать через юнит тестами ее просто не возможно. Помогите поправить так что-бы соблюдались принципы ООП.

Игра:

```
interface FirstMove {
    void firstMove();
}

interface Winner {
    Gamers getWinner();
}

public interface Round extends FirstMove, Winner {
}

public class Game implements Round {

    /**
     * Desc for play.
     */
    private Board desc = new Desc();

    /**
     * Winner.
     */
    private Gamers winner;

    /**
     * For console input.
     */
    private In input = new Input();

    /**
     * List contain all gamer: bot and user.
     */
    private ArrayList<Gamers> gamers = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Util class contain algorithm determining winner.
     */
    private Validation valid = new ValidationWinnerUtil();

    /**
     * Getter for winner.
     *
     * @return gamer which win.
     */
    @Override
    public Gamers getWinner() {
        return this.winner;
    }

    /**
     * Check correct move.
     *
     * @param player player which move.
     * @return true if move success. False if move fail
     */
    private boolean move(Gamers player) {
        player.setPosit();
        if (this.desc.getDesc()[player.getPosit().getY()][player.getPosit().getX()] == ' ') {
            this.desc.getDesc()[player.getPosit().getY()][player.getPosit().getX()] = player.getColor();
            return true;
        } else {
            System.err.println("Так ходить нельзя!");
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Determines fist move.
     */
    @Override
    public void firstMove() {
        this.desc.initDescSize();
        System.out.println("Кто ходит первым? Enter: Bot / I");
        if (this.input.getStrInput().toUpperCase().equals("BOT")) {
            this.fstMoveBot();
        } else {
            this.fstMoveUsr();
        }
        Printer.printDesc(this.desc.getDesc());
        this.loopMoves();
    }

    /**
     * Configurable statement game if bot move first.
     */
    private void fstMoveBot() {
        this.gamers.add(new Bot(Colors.X.getColor()));
        this.gamers.add(new User(Colors.O.getColor()));
    }

    /**
     * Configurable statement game if user choice move first.
     */
    private void fstMoveUsr() {
        this.gamers.add(new User(Colors.X.getColor()));
        this.gamers.add(new Bot(Colors.O.getColor()));
    }

    /**
     * Loop game process.
     */
    private void loopMoves() {
        Gamers winner = null;
        while (this.valid.gameCanGoOn(this.desc.getDesc())) {
            for (Gamers gamer : this.gamers) {

                if (this.valid.gameCanGoOn(this.desc.getDesc()) &&
                        this.move(gamer)
                        ) {

                    Printer.printDesc(this.desc.getDesc());
                    winner = gamer;

                } else if (this.valid.gameCanGoOn(this.desc.getDesc())) {
                    this.mistakeMove(gamer);
                    Printer.printDesc(this.desc.getDesc());
                }
            }
        }

        this.initResultGame(winner);
    }

    /**
     * Give more chance when player which mistake - try move in busy cell.
     *
     * @param gamer player which mistake.
     */
    private void mistakeMove(Gamers gamer) {
        while (!this.move(gamer)) {
            mistakeMove(gamer);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Init result game.
     *
     * @param winner gamer for estimated award.
     * @see TickTack#winners
     */
    private void initResultGame(Gamers winner) {
        if (!this.valid.emptyCellExist(this.desc.getDesc()) &&
                !this.valid.winnerDetermines(this.desc.getDesc())
                ) {

            System.out.println("Ничья.");
        } else if (this.valid.winnerDetermines(this.desc.getDesc())) {
            this.winner = winner;
            System.out.println(format("Победитель: %s", winner.getColor()));
        }
    }
}
```

Доска:

```
interface StatementDesk {

    /**
     * Getter for desc. Init infoDesc.
     * @return desc.
     */
    char[][] getDesc();
}

interface DescSize {

    /**
     * Init desc size in starting game.
     */
    void initDescSize();
}

public interface Board extends StatementDesk, DescSize, StubInputInterface {
}

public class Desc implements Board {

    /**
     * Information about statement desc for bot.
     */
    private static char[][] infoDesc;


    /**
     * Input for get console in.
     */
    private In input = new Input();

    /**
     * Desc for game.
     */
    private char[][] desc = new char[3][3];

    /**
     * Pointer on desc. It's information for bot about statement desc.
     *
     * @return current statement desc.
     */
    public static char[][] getInfoDesc() {
        return infoDesc;
    }

    /**
     * Use for test class StubInput.
     *
     * @param input emulation console input stream.
     */
    @Override
    public void setInput(In input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for desc. Init infoDesc.
     *
     * @return desc.
     */
    @Override
    public char[][] getDesc() {
        infoDesc = this.desc;
        return this.desc;
    }

    /**
     * For choice desc size.
     */
    @Override
    public void initDescSize() {
        System.out.println("Хотите использовать стандартный размер поля: y/n");
        String answer = this.input.getStrInput();
        if (answer.equals("y")) {
            System.out.println("Установлен стандартный размер поля: 3/3");
        } else if (answer.equals("n")) {
            this.initNonstandardDesc();
        }
        this.initContentDesc();
    }

    /**
     * Install desc nonstandard size.
     */
    private void initNonstandardDesc() {
        System.out.println("Введите размер сторон:");
        int i = this.input.getNumInput();
        this.desc = new char[i][i];
        System.out.println(format("Установлен размер поля: %s/%s", i, i));
    }

    /**
     * Fill desc empty call. Empty is ' '.
     */
    private void initContentDesc() {
        for (int i = 0; i != this.desc.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j != this.desc.length; j++) {
                this.desc[j][i] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ввод с консоли:

```
public class Input implements In {

    /**
     * Input stream to console.
     */
    private Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    /**
     * Console input for string.
     *
     * @return input string.
     */
    @Override
    public String getStrInput() {
        return this.scanner.next();
    }

    /**
     * Console input for int.
     *
     * @return input int.
     */
    @Override
    public int getNumInput() {
        return this.scanner.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Пользователь:

```
public class User implements Gamers, StubInputInterface {

    /**
     * Side on current game. May be 'X' or 'O'.
     */
    private final char color;
    /**
     * Position for move.
     */
    private Position posit = new Posit();
    /**
     * Console input for get data from user.
     */
    private In input = new Input();

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     *
     * @param color 'X' or 'O'.
     */
    public User(char color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for position.
     *
     * @return position.
     */
    @Override
    public Position getPosit() {
        return this.posit;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for color.
     *
     * @return color.
     */
    @Override
    public char getColor() {
        return this.color;
    }

    /**
     * For get data about move position from user by console input.
     */
    @Override
    public void setPosit() {
        System.out.println("По вертикали: ");
        this.posit.setX(this.input.getNumInput());
        System.out.println("По горизонтали: ");
        this.posit.setY(this.input.getNumInput());
    }

    /**
     * This setter for tests. He need for use StubInput class.
     *
     * @param input emulation console input.
     */
    @Override
    public void setInput(In input) {
        this.input = input;
    }
}
```

Компьютер-пользователь:

```
public class Bot implements Gamers {

    /**
     * Side for battle.
     */
    private final char color;
    /**
     * Current position.
     */
    private Position posit;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     *
     * @param color side battle. Init only once in begin game.
     */
    public Bot(char color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    /**
     * Getter gor color.
     *
     * @return color. May be 'X' or 'O'.
     */
    @Override
    public char getColor() {
        return this.color;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for current position.
     *
     * @return current position.
     */
    @Override
    public Position getPosit() {
        return this.posit;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for position.
     */
    @Override
    public void setPosit() {
        this.posit = this.generatePos();
    }

    /**
     * Generator new positions.
     *
     * @return position.
     */
    private Position generatePos() {
        char[][] desc = Desc.getInfoDesc();
        for (int i = 0; i < desc.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < desc.length; j++) {
                if (desc[j][i] == ' ') {
                    return new Posit(i, j);
                }
            }
        }
        System.err.println("Что-то пошло не так");
        return new Posit();
    }
}
```

Класс который создает серию партий и делает что-бы игра была до пяти побед:

```
class TickTack {

    /**
     * Contain gamers every time his win.
     */
    private ArrayList<Gamers> winners = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Contain all games.
     */
    private ArrayList<Round> games = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    TickTack() {
        this.initGames();
    }

    /**
     * Init all games.
     */
    private void initGames() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            this.games.add(new Game());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Loop games to 5 points.
     * After 5 wins one of players - break.
     */
    void start() {
        for (Round game : this.games) {
            if (this.resultAllGames(winners).equals("")) {
                game.firstMove();
                addWinner(game);
            } else {
                System.out.println(String.format(
                        "Победитель: %s", this.resultAllGames(winners)));
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add winner in list goals.
     *
     * @param game held game.
     */
    private void addWinner(Round game) {
        if (game.getWinner() != null)
            this.winners.add(game.getWinner());
    }

    /**
     * Check wins to five points.
     *
     * @param users list involved gamers.
     * @return "" if 5 points not success. if 5 points success name winner.
     */
    private String resultAllGames(ArrayList<Gamers> users) {
        int u = 0, b = 0;
        for (Gamers obj : users) {
            if (obj instanceof User) {
                u++;
                if (u == 5)
                    return "user";
            } else {
                b++;
                if (b == 5)
                    return "bot";
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Вот надо поправить чтобы было в стиле ООД. Ну поправлю сам надо подсказать  как и что. Вот.

Comment: выделите один класс. опишите его интерфейс - словами. дайте полный код.

Comment: Вот класс Game он отвечает за все движения на доске, крутит в цикле ходы то от одного пользователя то от другого, пока не определит победителя. Его интерфейсы добавил в начало.

Comment: выберите класс с наименьшим числом зависимостей. с него будет проще всего начать.

Comment: Тогда Desc. Добавил код интерфейсов. Должен хранить и создавать сам массив-доску,  при создании должна быть возможность выбора размера доски.

Comment: я дам свой вариант, через какое-то время

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот первичный вариант. Он сильно упрощен и я немного срезал углы. Но в целом идея должна быть понятна.

Класс Board

- отвечает за хранение состоя игрового поля
- позволяет менять состояние игрового поля
- преобразовывает игровое поле в строку

Я делал его по принципу: вначале тест - потом код.

```
package tictactoe;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class BoardTest {

    @Test
    public void constructor_createBoardSpecifiedSize() {
        Board subject = new Board(1);
        assertEquals(1, subject.getSize());
    }

    @Test
    public void getCell_onNewBoardReturnEmptyCell() throws Exception {
        Board subject = new Board(1);
        assertEquals(Cell.EMPTY, subject.getCell(0, 0));
    }

    @Test
    public void putMark_onNewBoardPutThisMarkOnBoard() throws Exception {
        Board subject = new Board(1);
        subject.putMark(Cell.X, 0, 0);
        assertEquals(Cell.X, subject.getCell(0, 0));
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalMove.class)
    public void putMark_inOccupiedCellThrowsException() throws Exception {
        Board subject = new Board(1);
        subject.putMark(Cell.X, 0, 0);
        subject.putMark(Cell.O, 0, 0);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalMove.class)
    public void putMark_EmptyMarkThrowsException() throws Exception {
        Board subject = new Board(1);
        subject.putMark(Cell.EMPTY, 0, 0);
    }

    @Test
    public void toString_onNewReturnsEmptyBoard() throws Exception {
        Board subject = new Board(3);
        assertEquals("+-+-+-+\n" +
                "| | | |\n" +
                "+-+-+-+\n" +
                "| | | |\n" +
                "+-+-+-+\n" +
                "| | | |\n" +
                "+-+-+-+\n", subject.toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void toString_onBoardWithTwoMarksReturnsCorrectBoard() throws Exception {
        Board subject = new Board(3);
        subject.putMark(Cell.X, 0, 0);
        subject.putMark(Cell.O, 2, 2);
        assertEquals("+-+-+-+\n" +
                "|x| | |\n" +
                "+-+-+-+\n" +
                "| | | |\n" +
                "+-+-+-+\n" +
                "| | |o|\n" +
                "+-+-+-+\n", subject.toString());
    }
}



class Board {
    private Cell[][] board;
    private int size;


    public Board(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        board = new Cell[size][size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                board[i][j] = Cell.EMPTY;
            }
        }
    }

    public Cell getCell(int row, int col) {
        return board[row][col];
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void putMark(Cell mark, int row, int col) throws IllegalMove {
        if(mark == Cell.EMPTY || board[row][col] != Cell.EMPTY) {
            throw new IllegalMove();
        }
        board[row][col] = mark;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            result.append(row(i));
        }
        result.append(horizontalLine());
        return result.toString();
    }

    private StringBuffer row(int r) {
        StringBuffer row = new StringBuffer();
        row.append(horizontalLine());
        row.append("|");
        row.append(Arrays.asList(board[r]).stream().map(Cell::toString).collect(Collectors.joining("|")));
        row.append("|\n");
        return row;
    }

    private StringBuffer horizontalLine() {
        StringBuffer line = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            line.append("+-");
        }
        line.append("+\n");
        return line;
    }
}

enum Cell {
    EMPTY(" "), X("x"), O("o");

    private String symbol;

    Cell(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return symbol;
    }
}

class IllegalMove extends Exception {}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Выглядит круто, только у void putMark(Cell mark, int row, int col) аж 3 параметра. Не многовато?

Comment: А какие варианты решения этого видите?

Comment: Пока не вижу. Но просто я часто слышу напутствие о том что аргументов чем меньше тем лучше. Вот и решил спросить. К стати вот эту строчку не как не прочитать row.append(Arrays.stream(board[r]).map(Cell::toString).collect(Collectors.joining("|"))); нельзя ли как-то проще записаеть ее?

Comment: Если аргументов больше 4, то имеет смысл посмотреть на дизайн ещё раз. Если дадите определение для слова проще, то будет понятнее. В целом этот метод плохой. Его лучше полностью переработать, а может быть даже убрать.

Comment: А проще я имею в виду что тут я так понимаю сокращенная форма записи двойного цикла или что-то в этом роде. Когда я делаю подобные вещи с коллекциями идея часто предлагает мне записать в одну строчку но после такого преобразования совсем ничего не понятно, а обратно не предлагает. Я пока коллекции не проходил и сторонюсь таких однострочных записей так как не знаю этих методов а с циклами все ясно становится.

Comment: Просто игнорируйте этот метод. Если сложно, то я могу его удалить.

Comment: Да к сожалению пока сложновато. Я вот что еще хотел спросить у меня все равно где-то будет ввод с консоли и этот вариант позволяет избежать зависимости класса доски от этого ввода как вы и говорили в самом начале. Но у меня есть классы игроков(пользователь должен получать ввод) и класс игры(тоже хочет спросить кто ходит первым). Как мне тут быть ведь я опять попаду в ситуацию где у меня несколько классов имеют разные экземпляры инпут? Вопрос вот в чем Если мне понадобится что-бы ввод было только в одном месте где он вы считаете должен быть в юзере или в игре?

Comment: у вас не должно быть много классов зависящих от  ввода пользователя. почитайте про SOLID.

Comment: вот я их как раз и прохожу))) получается я SRP нарушаю тыкая ввод везде и всюду...